# How can I format my submenu to act like my main navigation and stay open when hovering over it?

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, submenu

I'm using a bootstrap template and trying to create a submenu for the third menu item that will display four sub-items. For one, I can't get them to display properly, and I can't get them to stay open to hover over them. I'm a designer, not a developer, but I'm trying to learn a little. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I've looked through numerous Q&A's on here, but none seem to work for me. Ideally, I would like the submenu items to be dots that expand when you hover over the parent. I tried that at first, and almost got it, but they would close before I could hover over them, and they wouldn't open when you hovered over the parent. I feel like I'm close, but I've been working at this for the entire day.

```
<html>
<body>
  <header id="header" class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">

    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar nav-menu">
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#home" class="scrollto active">H<span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" class="scrollto">A<span>About</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio" class="scrollto">P<span>Portfolio</span></a>
          <ul class="nav-sub">
            <li><a href="/loupe2.html"><span>Sub 1</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/apexdrop2.html"><span>Sub 2</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/coursework.html"><span>Sub 3</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/other.html"><span>Sub 4</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #272829;
}

a {
  color: #0563bb;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #067ded;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9997;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.nav-menu {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-menu * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-menu ul {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-menu a,
.nav-menu a:focus {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 1);
  padding: 10px 18px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #f2f3f5;
  height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-menu a {
  border: 4px #1a1a1a solid;
  padding-left: 15px !important;
}


.nav-menu a span,
.nav-menu a:focus span {
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  display: none;
}

.nav-sub li,
.nav-sub li:focus {
  display: none;
}

.nav-menu a:hover,
.nav-menu .active,
.nav-menu .active:focus,
.nav-menu:hover > a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  border: 4px white solid;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.nav-menu a:hover span,
.nav-menu .active span,
.nav-menu .active:focus span,
.nav-menu:hover > a span {
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-menu a:hover,
.nav-menu:hover > a {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-menu a:hover span,
.nav-menu:hover > a span {
  display: block;
}

.main-nav > li:hover .nav-sub {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  display: block;
}

.main-nav > li:hover .nav-sub li span {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-sub {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.nav-sub li {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason was a margin-bottom: 8px on the last **a** tag, so there is a gap between the menu item and sub-menu. I made a quick fix for this issue. But there is still a lot of work to do.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #272829;
}

a {
  color: #0563bb;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #067ded;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9997;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.nav-menu {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-menu * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-menu ul {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-menu a,
.nav-menu a:focus {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 1);
  padding: 10px 18px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #f2f3f5;
  height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-menu .has-nav-sub a,
.nav-menu .has-nav-sub a:focus {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.nav-menu a {
  border: 4px #1a1a1a solid;
  padding-left: 15px !important;
}

.nav-menu a span,
.nav-menu a:focus span {
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  display: none;
}

.nav-sub li,
.nav-sub li:focus {
  display: none;
}

.nav-menu a:hover,
.nav-menu .active,
.nav-menu .active:focus,
.nav-menu:hover>a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  border: 4px white solid;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.nav-menu a:hover span,
.nav-menu .active span,
.nav-menu .active:focus span,
.nav-menu:hover>a span {
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-menu a:hover,
.nav-menu:hover>a {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-menu a:hover span,
.nav-menu:hover>a span {
  display: block;
}

.main-nav>li:hover .nav-sub {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

.main-nav>li:hover .nav-sub li span {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-sub {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.nav-sub li {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header id="header" class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">

    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar nav-menu">
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#home" class="scrollto active">H<span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" class="scrollto">A<span>About</span></a></li>
        <li class="has-nav-sub"><a href="#portfolio" class="scrollto">P<span>Portfolio</span></a>
          <ul class="nav-sub">
            <li><a href="/loupe2.html"><span>Sub 1</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/apexdrop2.html"><span>Sub 2</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/coursework.html"><span>Sub 3</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/other.html"><span>Sub 4</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured that part out, now I just to figure out how to format the buttons correctly.